# How to wait for a generator to finish? - Read CSV

Tags: python, csv, generator

I'm trying to read a very huge csv file (20 gb) using a generator, and execute some code after it has finished, but not success at the moment.

This is what i have:

```py
import csv
from queue import Queue

queue = Queue()

def load_file(filename: str):
    with open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=',')
        for rec in reader:
            yield rec
```

I've tried the next solutions:

A)
In this case, it prints almost immediately, not waiting for the loop to finish.

```py
gen = load_file('big_data.csv')

for value in gen:
    queue.put(value)

print('Execute some code after iterating the whole generator')
```

B)
In this case, the StopIteration is triggered after reading like 300-400 rows, causing to execute some code before the generator is fully completed.

```py
gen = load_file('big_data.csv')

while True:
    try:
        queue.put(next(gen))
    except StopIteration:
        print('Execute some code after iterating the whole generator')
        break
```

In the second case, it seems like the generator is reading the file too fast causing the StopIteration exception, but I'm not sure.

I've done a lot of research in the documentation and other forums, but haven't been able to find the solution.
I would appreciate any help in this issue, thanks.

Comment: What advantage would a generator have over reading the file normally? In the end you will have 20 GB in memory, no matter how. What are you really trying to achieve? IMHO you can't "read a file too fast", because your program will need to wait until the data was provided by the disk.

Comment: I agree with @Thomas. Regardless, what you are describing is not how the code — any of the snippets — should be working, so there must be something wrong. Can you upload the data file somewhere and post a link to it?

Comment: Your code works for me with a 94 MB file.

Comment: I forgot to mention that once the row is processed, it's freed from memory, so I'm not loading the whole dataset into memory. The generator reads line by line the file and yields the value to be put in a Queue, so multithreading executors can process the data avoiding memory overhead.

Comment: Multithreading with the GIL? Or Multiprocessing?

Comment: Multithreading with the GIL, because I need the executor to be able to access some class objects.

Comment: And yes, in the second case, the read rows are always in the range between 300 and 400. I know this because part of the process is to insert the processed row in a database. So only about 300-400 rows are only inserted every time. My take would be that the csv reader is reading in batches and maybe there is a minimum pause between each batch causing the stop-iteration exception. But the documentation doesn't mention anything regarding this.